# Why doesn't std::swap work on vector<bool> elements under Clang/Win?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clang, c++17, std

I have code like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
   std::vector<bool> vb{true, false};
   std::swap(vb[0], vb[1]);
}
```

Arguments about the sanity of `vector<bool>` aside, this was working just fine on:

- Clang for Mac
- Visual Studio for Windows
- GCC for Linux

Then I tried building it with Clang on Windows and received the following error (abridged):

```
error: no matching function for call to 'swap'
                                std::swap(vb[0], vb[1]);
                                ^~~~~~~~~

note: candidate function [with _Ty = std::_Vb_reference<std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, $1 = void] not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument
inline void swap(_Ty& _Left, _Ty& _Right) _NOEXCEPT_COND(is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<_Ty>&&
```

I'm surprised that the results differ across implementations.

Why does it not work with Clang on Windows?

Comment: So I guess the clarification needed is: Is the result of `operator[]` an lvalue? and can `std::swap` operate on rvalues and xvalues?

Comment: @Mgetz Yes. No. In that order. This question was asked "for real" in private the other day, and I thought it sufficiently entertaining that the answer was "Clang/Win isn't broken; the code was broken _this whole time_ but the mainstream toolchain combos never bothered to tell you" to write it up here :P

Comment: Just as an FYI, this does not compile in VS 2019 with `/permissive-` (conformance), which should generally be used anyway ;)

Comment: @ChrisMM Indeed! Conformance mode _off_ was a part of the puzzle. (Though we did not know that before looking into it!) And my answer does point that out :P

Comment: Indeed, which is the default, sadly :(

Comment: @ChrisMM Not any more! [_"By default, the /permissive- option is set in new projects created by Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5 and later versions. It is not set by default in earlier versions."_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Thanks, I did not know that. Apparently I'm a bit out of date on that one, and can remove some useless lines from my CMake files now

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The standard doesn't require this to compile on *any* toolchain!

First recall that `vector<bool>` is weird and subscripting it gives you a temporary object of a proxy type called `std::vector<bool>::reference`, rather than an actual `bool&`.

The error message is telling you that it cannot bind this temporary to a non-`const` lvalue reference in the generic `template <typename T> std::swap(T& lhs, T& rhs)` implementation.

#### Extensions!

However, it turns out that libstdc++ [defines an overload](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_bvector.h#L118) for `std::swap(std::vector<bool>::reference, std::vector<bool>::reference)`, but this is an extension to the standard (or, if it is in there, I can't find any evidence for it).

libc++ [does this too](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/__bit_reference#L86).

I'd guess that the Visual Studio stdlib implementation, which you're still using, *doesn't*, but then to add insult to injury [you can bind temporaries to lvalue references](https://godbolt.org/z/Cn1vEm) in VS (unless you're using conformance mode), so the standard, "generic", `std::swap` function works until you substitute the VS compiler for the stricter Clang compiler.

As a result, you've been relying on extensions on all of the three toolchains for which it did work for you, and the Clang on Windows combination is the only one actually exhibiting strict compliance.

*(In my opinion, those three toolchains [should have diagnosed this](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.compliance#8) so you didn't ship non-portable code this whole time. )*

#### What now?

It may be tempting to add your own specialisation of `std::swap` and `std::vector<bool>::reference`, but you're not allowed to do this for standard types; indeed, it would conflict with the overloads that libstdc++ and libc++ have chosen to add as extensions.

So, to be portable and compliant, **you should change your code**.

Perhaps a good old-fashioned:

```
const bool temp = vb[0];
vb[0] = vb[1];
vb[1] = temp;
```

Or make use of [the special static member function that does exactly what you wanted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool/swap):

```
std::vector<bool>::swap(vb[0], vb[1]);
```

Also spellable as follows:

```
vb.swap(vb[0], vb[1]);
```

Comment: Regarding the *but it's not supposed to* AFAIK they are allowed to do so.  As long as they don't break conforming code they can extend the implementation to make broken code "OK".

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica Well, okay. Don't they have to at least diagnose the use of such things, though? http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.compliance#8

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica is there any language that forbids this extension?

Comment: @Mgetz Sorry, I'm not conversant in all extant languages so I cannot answer that

Comment: I'm not sure if *use such extensions that are ill-formed according to this document* applies.  They added an overload that takes a `std::vector<bool>::reference` so nothing is actually ill-formed.  To me it sounds like using something like `char * foo = "bar";` would require a diagnostic since that is ill-formed.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica The program's ill-formed without the extension, i.e. it's ill-formed according to the document. I interpret the passage as meaning "you should warn when the program only compiles because of extensions", just as GCC gives you a "ISO C requires string literals to be `const`" warnings. Ideally we'd get a "ISO C++ does not support this form of swappageness" warning from the code in the question but I've never seen one (ofc that'd be tougher to implement for an extension that's in the lib, than for an extension that's in the core language)

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica snark aside, is there any reason that `std::vector<bool>::reference` shouldn't support `std::swap`?

Comment: @Mgetz It's a temporary returned from `op[]` and temporaries don't bind to non-`const` refs

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica Ah, in other words, I think the word "program" is a crucial part of the quote that you missed out; they're talking about "ill-formed programs (that use extensions)", not "ill-formed extensions".

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Good point.  Looks like they should then.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica looks like the temporary is returned by value. So while that logic would hold if it was _an actual reference_ the practicalities mean it's not and thus should be legally swappable. This seems like a defect honestly. http://eel.is/c++draft/vector.bool

Comment: @Mgetz A value returned from a function is a temporary... Returning a reference on the other hand is fine as that's an lvalue expression which'll bind just fine to swap's args

Comment: @NathanOliver I think this extension is conforming: [\[global.functions\]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/global.functions#2), especially [footnote 181](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/global.functions#footnote-181).